# How Could David Kill the Ger Amaleki Based on Halacha?

Tags: death, capital-punishment, samuel-shmuel-book-of, edim-witnesses

In Shmuel Bet, David Hamelech kills the Ger Haamaleki for killing Shaul.
However, the only reason he knew this was because of his own admission.

How does this relate to אין אדם משים עצמו רשע, the fact that one can't incriminate themself?

See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for the story.

Comment: does ein adam... apply to Jews and non-Jews alike? The meforshim say that a non-Jew can be put to death without the eidim that would be required to put a Jew to death. They also say that Dovid put the Amaleki to death for other reasons.

Comment: it sounds like he was Jewish though

Comment: I was thinking maybe because we can't take amaleki geirim, but I'm not sure if that is a real halacha, although I have heard it

Comment: what else do the meforshim say?

Comment: The meforshim mention that we can't take Amaleki converts so he wasn't Jewish. https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.1.13?lang=bi&with=Chomat%20Anakh%20on%20II%20Samuel&lang2=en

Comment: Anyway, the Rambam says that when a king executes someone, he doesn't have to follow the normal rules of evidence (Hilchos Melachim 3:10).

Comment: @rosends Accepting Amaleki converts is a subject of debate. See my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100636/can-descendants-of-amalek-become-jewish/100667#100667).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exact question is asked by Malbim.

> איך הרגו על פי הודאת עצמו ואין עדים והתראה

He provides three possible answers:

1. The fellow was not Jewish and just as other judicial conditions do not apply to non-Jews, it is possible that inadmissibility of self-incriminating testimony does not apply to non-Jews.
2. The fellow was Jewish but David was allowed to kill him in his capacity as king even without formal court proceedings.
3. The Sages say that the fellow was Doeg, and even though he could not be held culpable for this self-admitted killing, he was culpable for the destruction of Nov the city of priests, and thus David executed him for that.

> דמך על ראשך אם נאמר שהיה עמלקי ממש שבן נח נהרג בלא התראה ונהרג אף על הטריפה ונהרג בדיין אחד ובעד אחד י"ל שהוא הדין שנהרג בהודאת עצמו כמו שנהרג על פי קרוב (וצ"ע בזה לדינא) ועל זה אמר פיך ענה בך ואם נאמר שהיה ישראל נהרג מדין המלכות כמ"ש כי פיך ענה בך לאמר אנכי מותתי את משיח ה' כדי שלא יזידו להרים יד במלך ולקבלת חכמינו זכרונם לברכה שהיה דואג שהיה חייב מיתה מכבר על נוב עיר הכהנים שעל זה אמר דמיך בלשון רבים רמז לו שהגם שעל הריגת שאול אין אדם נאמן על עצמו בכל זה פיך ענה בך כי כבר היית הגורם על הריגת הכהנים והכהן המשיח שזה רמז באמרו אנכי מותתי את משיח ה׳

Ralbag, while not explicitly asking this question, addresses it by saying that David executed the fellow as a *hora'at sha'ah*, a temporary extra-judicial ruling, so that people wouldn't think that it is trivial to kill the king.

> ואעפ"י שלא היו שם עדים והיה מרשיע את עצמו והיה מפני זה פטור בדין הנה עשה דוד זה להוראת שעה שלא יקלו האנשים לשלוח ידם במלכות ולזאת הסבה בעינה נזהר משלוח יד בשאול כשהיה במערה ואעפ"י שהיה רודפו והיה מותר להרגו

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this completely answers the question but the [Mechilta 17:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_d%27Rabbi_Yishmael.17.16.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> ר' אליעזר אומר: נשבע המקום בכסא הכבוד שלו שאם יבא אחד מכל האומות שיקבלוהו, ולעמלק ולביתו לא יקבלוהו, שנאמר: "ויאמר דוד אל הנער המגיד לו אי מזה אתה ויאמר בן איש גר עמלקי אנכי" (שמואל ב א יג). נזכר לדוד באותה שעה מה שנאמר למשה רבינו: אם יבא מכל האומות שבעולם להתגייר שיקבלוהו, ומביתו שלא יקבלוהו. מיד "ויאמר אליו דוד דמך על ראשך כי פיך ענה בך"
>
> *R. Eliezer says: The L rd swears by His throne of glory: If there comes a man of all the nations to be proselytized, he will be accepted; but Amalek and his household will not be accepted, viz. ([II Samuel 1:13](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.1.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "And David asked the youth who told him: Where are you from? And he said: I am the son of an Amalekite convert." David remembered at that time what had been told to Moses our teacher, that if there comes a man of all the nations of the world to be proselytized, he should be accepted, but if he is of the house of Amalek, he should not be accepted, whereupon (II Samuel , Ibid.) "David said to him: Your blood is on your own head, for your mouth testified against you."* (Sefaria translation)

Comment: What does the validity of his father's conversion have to do with his status?  That would go by his mother.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100636/can-descendants-of-amalek-become-jewish/100667#100667) for a discussion of whether this source is to be taken at face value.

Comment: @Alex -fascinating and yasher kochacho on a phenomenal post over there!

Comment: @Dov Thank you.